# Bash script error

Tags: bash, shell

My bash skills need fine-tuning.

If I comment out line B (i.e. so I have a full path defined), the script runs fine.
If I uncomment line B (i.e. I build the path up) I get an error. Why?

Here's the script (used to run Apple's `instruments` tool):

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE="foo"
TEST="bar"
APP="etc"

PATH="/Users/snowcrash"

SCRIPT="/Users/snowcrash/scriptA.js"  # Line A runs fine
SCRIPT="$PATH/scriptA.js" # Line B gives me 'instruments: command not found'

instruments -w "$DEVICE" -t "$TEST" "$APP" -e UIASCRIPT "$SCRIPT"
```

Comment: Don't use PATH.  Don't know if that's the cause of your error, but PATH is the list of directories that the shell looks for executables.

Comment: doh! yes, that was the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested it with GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1), and my local variable could always override the exported one, even if it was called `PATH`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros, changing the local variable will always immediately and automatically change the environment variable it came from.

Comment: @SnowCrash, btw, the best-practices way to avoid this is to use at least partially lowercase (if not all-lowercase) names for shell variables that are neither environment variables or builtins (the two category for which all-caps names are reserved).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That information is consistent with my test, thus reinforcing my doubts that using the `PATH` variable caused that problem in above code snippet as @Snow Crash stated in comment #2.

Comment: @MichaelJaros, pardon? That setting the local variable PATH also updates the environment variable PATH is _entirely_ consistent with `instruments: command not found`, assuming that `instruments` isn't in `/Users/snowcrash`.

Comment: @racraman: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Er, yes :) It's late here.